# Dependency issues with python's plotly and dash

Tags: python, plotly, dashboard, plotly-dash

I am trying to construct a dashboard in python using plotly and dash that will use a slider to change the range (x-axis) of a graph.  The x-axis contains dates.

I am following the example for a slider on on plotly's website (https://dash.plot.ly/dash-core-components/rangeslider).  The slider example works fine in my environment. When I replace the min, max values for the slider with the minimum and maximum date values in my dataframe as follows:

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.RangeSlider(
        id='slider',
        min = df['date'].min(),
        max = df['date'].max()
    ),
    html.Div(id='slider-container')
])
```

my browser throws the following error: 'Error loading dependencies'. 'date' in my dataframe is a pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp

I have uninstalled and reinstalled dash, dash-renderer, dash-html-components, dash-core-components and plotly as per https://github.com/plotly/dash/issues/82

Any suggestions on what is going wrong?  The complete code for my example is:

```
external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.RangeSlider(
        id='slider',
        min = df['date'].min(),
        max = df['date'].max()
    ),
    html.Div(id='slider-container') ])


@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('slider-container', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('slider', 'value')])
def update_output(value):
    return 'You have selected "{}"'.format(value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

And this works fine if slider values are set to:

```
    dcc.RangeSlider(
        id='slider',
        min=0,
        max=20,
        step=0.5,
        value=[5, 15]
```

Comment: 'Error loading dependencies' is an error generated by Dash to let you know there is a problem in your app code, usually in callback functions. The installation is probably ok, the problem is local to your app. I'll look into it and see if I can help.

Comment: Please add an example DF, preferably directly inside the python code (e.g. `df = pd.DataFrame({...})`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `RangeSlider` can't work directly with `Timestamp` objects. You need to convert them into numerical ([POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)) timestamps to work with the slider, and convert them again into objects inside the callback function.

The following worked for me:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

# Demo dataframe with a 'date' column
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.to_datetime(np.linspace(1500000000, 1550000000, 9), unit='s')})

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.RangeSlider(
        id='slider',
        min=df['date'].min().timestamp(),
        max=df['date'].max().timestamp(),
        value=[df['date'].min().timestamp(), df['date'].max().timestamp()],
    ),
    html.Div(id='slider-container')
])


@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('slider-container', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('slider', 'value')])
def update_output(value):
    if value:
        return 'You have selected "{}"'.format(list(pd.to_datetime(value, unit='s')))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, this works for me also.  Appreciate you solving this (and sorry for the delay in marking as accepted).